# Use of other ICU patients as control group

Tags: experiment-design, case-control-study, medicine

I am reviewing an article that is not yet published, so I cannot be too specific.

Briefly, the authors did an unmatched case-control study.  The cases were patients admitted to the ICU for a specific reason, the controls were all other patients admitted to the same ICU over the same period.  The authors then say that certain variables are risk factors for the condition.

My concern is that using other ICU patients seems like a poor control group. If a variable is a risk factor for the condition, then, surely, the same variable is a protective factor against any other condition that could put a person in an ICU. Since all of those are bad things, this seems like a big flaw.

But ... Maybe I am missing something?

References or ideas about this design would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you've missed anything, this seems like a very poor choice for a control group. It's highly unlikely to represent  general population or even the broader population of patients who might develop the condition.